# How to manage picklist values of a field in Salesforce?

Tags: picklist, record-type

Here is the scenario where I am strucked: In OSR object, there is a picklist field 'Status'. In this field, I have 5 values(Not Submitted,Open,In Progress,Completed,Rejected) but I want to display only one picklist value in status field(Not Submitted) before an OSR record is created. I am able to display only "Not Submitted" value by creating a new record type and placing "Not Submitted" value as a default one.

But when a record gets saved and submitted for Approval, its status is changed to "Open" and at that time, it is displaying only "Open" and "Not Submitted" values but I also want "In Progress" value to be displayed.

I know there is a way to do this but how I don't know.
Any suggestion on this really helpful !

Thanks in advance !

[image]

[image]

Comment: Implementing the above scenario is not possible using the same Record Type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to approach this problem, but all of them use some work on components other than the picklist itself.

- You can extend the Record Type solution you've already adopted. Use automation to update the Record Type on the record each time it enters a new stage that should expose different picklist values, and expose only the desired picklist values on each Record Type. For example, you could use an action on initial submission into an approval process to change to a new record type that exposes different picklist values.
- You can build a custom UI to manage edits to the object and write code to display only the relevant picklist values.
- You can disable edits on this field, which from your description sounds like it mostly *shouldn't* be user-editable, and update it exclusively via automation based on other events (record created, record submitted for approval, etc).
- You can disable edits on the field and allow it to be edited only by executing Quick Actions on the object with the correct value supplied as a Predefined Field Value.
- You can require updates to the field to go through a Screen Flow.

I'm sure there are more possibilities, but the common thread is that you either control the UI or control the edit functionality through other on-platform tools.

Comment: Basically, when a record is created and submitted for Approval, its status is "Open" and at that time, the current Approver should be able to change to status to "In Progress" or keep it as it is. It would be great if this can be done without coding. Can you please elaborate the first point you have written ?